# General technique of proving limit exists as x approaches infinity

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm looking for a way of proving that $f(x)$ will have some limit (without specifying what it is) as $x \to \infty$.

To make this more concrete, I'm asked to (1) prove the limit exists and (2) find the limit of the sequence given by $a_{n+1}=\sqrt{6a_n}$ where $0 < a_1 < 6$. I can show that the limit should be 6, well, maybe not rigorously enough, but it's easy to see that anyway.  Where I'm having problems is what technique to use to show that this sequence at all converges.  I can't work from the $\sigma-\epsilon$ definition of limit because it requires explicit reference to the limit I *didn't* find yet.

Put differently, I need some way of approaching this problem which only relies on knowing what the terms of sequence are, but not what the limit is.  I have a feeling that Cauchy definition of the limit may be helpful here, but I can't find it stated as a formula (only as a paragraph of prose), which isn't helping.

Obviously, this is a homework, so no complete solution please, just an advise on the general method of finding one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below are the steps:

- Given that $a_1 \in (0,6)$, use induction to conclude that $a_{n+1} \in (a_n,6)$.
- Hence, you have a monotone increasing sequence bounded above.
- Use monotone sequence theorem to conclude the sequence converges to a limit say $L$.
- Use the recurrences and properties of limits to obtain that $L=6$.

Comment: Oh, right, the monotone sequence theorem, I should've remembered we talked about it in class! :) Thanks!