# How can I prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 21$ using the $\epsilon - N$ definition?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

The exercise goes like this...

Let $(a_n) \subset \mathbb{R}$ given by $a_1=\sqrt{21}$ and $a_{n+1}=\sqrt{21a_n}$

a) Find the value of $L=\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n$

b) Prove that $L=\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n$

I managed to prove that the sequence is monotonic increasing and bounded above by $21$ by induction so i can assume that $(a_n)$ converges and show that $L=21$ using a little bit of algebra. But for b) I'm asked to prove the fact using the $\epsilon - N$ definition of limit

I'm used to struggle a lot proving limits for non-recursive sequences using the formal definition of limit, so in this case I don't really know how to proceed.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1248658/42969

Comment: i still can't figure out how to proceed with proving this thing using $\epsilon - N$ definition

Answer (score 1):

Try to show that $a_{n}=21^{1-\frac{1}{2^{n}}}$. What is the limit thereof?

Answer (score 0):

You proved that the limit $L$ exists, now only observe that the limit must satisfy
$$L=\sqrt{21 L}$$
because of course $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} a_n = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_{n+1} = \sqrt{21\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n}$ by the continuity of the square root and multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

$$a_n=\sqrt{21\sqrt{21\sqrt{21\sqrt{21\sqrt{21...}}}}}$$

$$\implies \dfrac{ (a_n)^2}{21}=a_n$$

$$\implies a_n=21$$

Or more straightforward,

$$\sqrt{21\sqrt{21\sqrt{21\sqrt{21\sqrt{21...}}}}}=21^\frac{1}{2}\times 21^\frac{1}{4}\times 21^\frac{1}{8} \cdots=21^{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+\cdots}=21^{\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{1-\frac{1}{2}}}=21.$$